# Music App: order by album release date in iOS 9?

Tags: itunes, music.app

When I tap in the artist in the Music app, I see the list of their albums.
Is there a way to make this list sorted by year (release date)?
I'm on iOS 9

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there seems to be no way to do this natively, but [Picky](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/picky-filter-queue-browse/id497110916?mt=8) handles it nicely.